# Origins and Industrial Applications of stochastic processes (eg. Brownian motion) on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am studying BM on Riemannian manifolds and I am curious how this theory started. In the references below (esp. in Hsu's exposition), you will find many applications of that theory such as a probabilistic proof of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem.

I am also curious about the industrial applications (if any yet) given that Riemannian geometry is used in Machine learning and statistics.

Thanks anyhow

In case you are interested
[1]https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/probability/sympo/PSS03abstract.pdf
[2]http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~ehsu/Brownian%20Motion%20and%20Riemannian%20Geometry.pdf (proof of Atiyah Singer index thm)

Comment: There seem to be two _different_ questions you are asking here. One is "how this theory started"; the other is "are there industrial applications". Which one would you like answers to?

Comment: yeah sorry, I was just fixing that. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest "industrial" application I know is in the context of microwave engineering: the eigenvalues of the transmission matrix through a waveguide with random scatterers perform a Brownian motion in hyperbolic space as a function of the length of the waveguide.

[Waveguides with Random Inhomogeneities and Brownian Motion In the Lobachevsky Plane](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1104038) (1959).

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat recent engineering application is in study of dynamics and control on manifolds such as SO(3), which is the manifold on which the (position) state of a rotating rigid body (such as a satellite) evolves.
For inference/filtering problems (i.e. trying to estimate the position on SO(3) given some noisy measurements), it is required to perform uncertainty propagation on these manifolds.
Here's a reference:
http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1515